# Apexcharts - React js Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): t.every is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm trying to set dynamic data into my pie chart using Apexcharts, but I'm running into an error.

```
class ApexChartPie1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
 
      this.state = {
        series: this.state={
          dataL : []
        },
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 380,
            type: 'pie',
          },
          labels: ['LOST', 'WON'],
          responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 480,
            options: {
              chart: {
                width: 200
              },
              legend: {
                position: 'bottom'
              }
            }
          }]
        },         
      };
    }

  
    async componentDidMount(){
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/designe/pieone")
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then((data) =>{
        this.setState({dataL : data})
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div id="chart">
          <ReactApexChart options={this.state.options} series={this.state.series} type="pie" width={380} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

The error I'm getting:

`React js Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): t.every is not a function`

Comment: `this.state = { series: this.state={` is this a typo?

Answer (score 2):

One problem that I see is that you are nesting references to `this.state` and Apexcharts is looking for `series` to be an array of chart values.

You could try changing your setup in the constructor:

```
this.state = {
    series: [], 
    options: {
        // Your options
    }
};
```

And then add your data in the Axios call with:

```
this.setState({series: data})
```